# Constraining generic parameter to be abstract

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

Is it possible to specify a constraint to a C# generic parameter, where that parameter must be abstract?

I currently have a method where the generic parameter must have a parameterless constructor but I've now run in to a scenario where I need an abstract T so I was hoping to overload the method with one that accepts only abstract Ts

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> SomeParam) where T:SomeBase, new()
{
    T tThing = new T();
    // do something simple
}

public static T SomeOtherMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> SomeParam) where T:SomeBase, new()
{
    T tThing = new T();
    // do something simple
}

public static void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> SomeParam) where T:SomeBase, abstract()
{
    // do something clever
}

public static T SomeOtherMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> SomeParam) where T:SomeBase, abstract()
{
    // do something clever
}
```

If, as I suspect, the answer is "you can't do this", are there any sensible workarounds?

Comment: There is no constraint for abstract - and its not clear what you want to do that you think you need an abstract constraint. You can constrain to a class, which is abstract (eg, `SomeBase` in your code).

Comment: The new-constraint simply exists to determine if you have a value- or a reference-type. However I can´t see any practical use for an abstract-constraint. What benefit of an `IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass>`do you hope that `IEnumerable<MyClass>` won´t also have?

Comment: How about inheriting *SomeBase* into a new abstract class and then using *where T : NewAbstractClass* ?

Comment: If you'[ve got a method which needs to instantiate `T`s, and now you find yourself wanting to call it with an `abstract` `T`, it looks like it's time to rethink/rewrite, doesn't it?

Comment: I've since discovered that actually this won't work in my scenario but I think it's still a good question.
It stems from a bad decision that was made 2 or more years ago, and I'm not about to retrofit lots of code to fix it.
Methods on T need to be invoked in order to decide the correct action(s) for the list. To do that it instantiates a new T, invokes the methods and then processes the list. Ideally those methods would be static, or attributes but we're stuck with them being instance methods and/or properties.
The abstract version of the method would find some other way to deal with this.

Comment: What is the purpose of such a constraint?

Comment: Constraints don't affect overload resolution, so even if you could do this it wouldn't work as you desire anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot instruct the compiler to check that the type parameter is abstract. But you can do a runtime check.

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> SomeParam) where T:SomeBase
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if(type.IsAbstract)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot use SomeMethod with type {0} because it is abstract.", type.FullName)); 
    }

    // Do the actual work
}
```

Or:

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> SomeParam) where T:SomeBase
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if(type.IsAbstract)
    {
        SomeMethodAbstract<T>(SomeParam);
    }
    else
    {
        SomeMethodNonAbstract<T>(SomeParam);
    }
}
```